# How to read ol and li elements dynamically without using xpath

Tags: selenium

I'm new to selenium and Below is my HTML and i want to display sons of Dhritrashtra and grandsons of pandu (without using xpath). I've tried methods like getText and getLinkText but it's not working for me. Please help.Thanks.

Kuru

1. Shantanu

   1. Vichitravirya
     1. Dhritrashtra

        1. Duryodhana
        2. Dushasana
        3. Dussalan
        4. Jalagandha
        5. Sama
        6. Saha
        7. Vindha
        8. Anuvindha
        9. Durmukha
        10. Chitrasena
        11. Durdarsha
        12. Durmarsha
        13. Dussaha
        14. Durmada
        15. Vikarna
        16. Dushkarna
        17. Durdhara
        18. Vivinsati
        19. Durmarshana
        20. Durvishaha
        21. Durvimochana
        22. Dushpradharsha
        23. Durjaya
        24. Jaitra
        25. Bhurivala
        26. Ravi
        27. Jayatsena
        28. Sujata
        29. Srutavan
        30. Srutanta
        31. Jayat
        32. Chitra
        33. Upachitra
        34. Charuchitra
        35. Chitraksha
        36. Sarasana
        37. Chitrayudha
        38. Chitravarman
        39. Suvarma
        40. Sudarsana
        41. Dhanurgraha
        42. Vivitsu
        43. Subaahu
        44. Nanda
        45. Upananda
        46. Kratha
        47. Vatavega
        48. Nishagin
        49. Kavashin
        50. Paasi
        51. Vikata
        52. Soma
        53. Suvarchasas
        54. Dhanurdhara
        55. Ayobaahu
        56. Mahabaahu
        57. Chithraamga
        58. Chithrakundala
        59. Bheemaratha
        60. Bheemavega
        61. Bheemabela
        62. Ugraayudha
        63. Kundhaadhara
        64. Vrindaaraka
        65. Dridhavarma
        66. Dridhakshathra
        67. Dridhasandha
        68. Jaraasandha
        69. Sathyasandha
        70. Sadaasuvaak
        71. Ugrasravas
        72. Ugrasena
        73. Senaany
        74. Aparaajitha
        75. Kundhasaai
        76. Dridhahastha
        77. Suhastha
        78. Suvarcha
        79. Aadithyakethu
        80. Ugrasaai
        81. Kavachy
        82. Kradhana
        83. Kundhy
        84. Bheemavikra
        85. Alolupa
        86. Abhaya
        87. Dhridhakarmaavu
        88. Dhridharathaasraya
        89. Anaadhrushya
        90. Kundhabhedy
        91. Viraavy
        92. Chithrakundala
        93. Pradhama
        94. Amapramaadhy
        95. Deerkharoma
        96. Suveeryavaan
        97. Dheerkhabaahu
        98. Kaanchanadhwaja
        99. Kundhaasy
        100. Virajas
     2. Pandu

        1. Yudhishtir

           1. Prativindhya
        2. Bhim

           1. Sutasoma
           2. Ghatotkch
        3. Arjun

           1. Srutakirti
           2. Babhruvahan
        4. Nakul

           1. Satanika
        5. Sahadev

           1. Shrutkarma

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML. For your example, you don't need to list the HTML for all elements, just a representative sample.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, I'll try to be more precise next time.

Comment: You still need to fix this question. It's not complete. You haven't shown the HTML, you've provided a text list which we can't do anything with and you haven't provided the code you have tried. Your question is about to get closed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your query:

1. It's not mandatory to use xpath always. As per the Selenium Documentation & standards, consider the following attributes in sequence: id, name, css, linktext, xpath. If still unable to detect the element try for css/xpath with multiple attributes like class, src, etc.
2. Once you can identify the element then only you will be able to retrieve the properties of the element like getText() & getLinkText().
3. Most important, you have provided the copy of the text from the website. It's impossible to identify an an element from the website text to help you out. You need to provide some relevant part of the HTML DOM inorder to enable us to help you. You can look into the PageSource of any webpage to know the properties (id/name/css/xpath) of the elements. For that, while you are on a webpage, you can right-click and select "View Page Source". For Mozilla Firefox you can download & install extensions ​like Firepath & Firebug to know the properties of an element.
4. Finally you have to write some code either in Java/Python/C# to open a browser through Selenium of your choice, open a website and perform certain actions with different elements present on the webpage.

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: this is something which i tried.  public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("http://localhost:90/finsys/task2.html");
  List<WebElement> obj1 = driver.findElements(By.tagName("ol"));
  WebElement obj2 = obj1.get(0).findElement(By.linkText("Dhritrashtra"));
  System.out.println(obj2.getText());

Comment: below is sample HTML
<li>Kuru
                <ol>
                    <li>Shantanu
                        <ol>
                            <li>Vichitravirya</li>
                                <ol>
                                  <li>Dhritrashtra
                                             <ol><li>Duryodhana</li><li>Dushasana</li>

Comment: @AlpeshJangam I have provided the answer to your question depending upon the information you have provided (without the HTML DOM) in your question. Unfortunately I won't be able to access your localhost to access the application. So if my answer have helped you to get the idea of what needs to be done please accept this answer as a Solution and raise a new question with more granular details. I will be glad to help you out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact syntax your html has but You can use cssSelector as below per my assumptions of your html elements for both your queries:

1) `ul ol ol ol li:nth-child(n) - n= element index`

2) `ul ol ol ol:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(n) li:nth-child(1) - n= element index`

Comment: Thank you for answer. I need generic approach as in the position of the li and ul elements keep on changing on every reload.

Comment: I don't understand what keeps on changing, can you provide me URL?